# Any non-GUI way of installing a new theme for QT Apps like vbox or vlc while in an Gnome environment?

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, themes, qt5, kde5

I'm using the Numix GTK theme in Gnome Shell and I've found it's analog for KDE / Qt here: https://codeload.github.com/numixproject/numix-kde-theme/zip/master

I've downloaded the theme and I was wondering if there was some non-gui dependent way of installing the theme by modifying some config files or swapping out some files?

I'm trying to avoid GUIs because I'd rather not have to install hundreds of megabytes of KDE dependencies just to get into the KDE theme GUIs.